# Pricing in "Bitcoin days destroyed"

Tags: exchange-rate, value, bitcoin-days-destroyed

Is it possible to use "Bitcoin days destroyed" as unit of currency? If yes, how to price anything using this? If no, why not?

Answer (score 1):

In other words, a system where coins that have not been spent recently are worth more? I suppose you could do such a thing, but it doesn't seem useful; typically friction in economies is a bad thing.

But I imagine you'd price things just like in any other market: supply and demand.

Comment: On the other hand, "old money" would mean something entirely different. /s

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just how Proof-of-stake altcoins works?
In those systems, your wallet amount grows as the time passes. Ie: 10% over a year.
I think this is very similar to bitcoindaysdestroyed-coin.